# User written job is giving error regarding SAS Formats

Tags: sas, olap-cube

I am migrating from OpRisk Monitor 3.4 (SAS 9.1) to EGRC 5.1 (SAS 9.3).

There are some user written jobs which create some datasets necessary for the OLAPCubes & InformationMaps which inturn are used by some reports. There is one job which ends in giving an error. The error is

```
ERROR: The format BL was not found or could not be loaded.
ERROR: The format BASEL_BL was not found or could not be loaded.
ERROR: The format GEOGRAPHY was not found or could not be loaded.
ERROR: The format PRODUCT was not found or could not be loaded.
```

My understanding of this is that these are some custom formats/informats which are not available in the 5.1 which I will have to migrate from 3.4. Thats just My understanding, I have never worked with FORMATS before.  Any help how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can migrate the formats from the old system to the new using the below commands, that is if the formats are custom.

```
PORC FORMAT CNTLIN= & CNTLOUT=
```

But of the formats are standard, the above is not required we only need to make sure if the formats in different version have same names. In my scenario OpRisk Monitor 3.4 (SAS 9.1) to EGRC 5.1 (SAS 9.3) have different names. The difference is that the later version used `_FMT` at the end of every format name.

Answer (score 0):

Use the OPTIONS statement for ignoring this error. "OPTIONS NOFMTERR;" in the autoexec.sas for EGRC and that will help you ignore the error and run fine. Remember to remove the options statement after use.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. OP wants to solve the error, not ignore it. This should be a comment.

Comment: @usandfriends - This solves the error by ignoring it! which part of it did you not understand? If there are custom formats which are used in the OLAP cubes then the simple thing would be to migrate them first , follow the sequence for migration FOLDER --> LIBRARY --> FILE -->
JOB --> FORMAT --> TABLE --> CUBE

Comment: I see (http://studysas.blogspot.in/2010/02/error-format-xxxx-was-not-found-or.html)

Comment: actually I figured out the solution, I migrated the custom formats from the old system to the new system using PORC FORMAT CNTLIN= & CNTLOUT= statements.